# Ubuntu is asking for password for small things

Tags: wireless, password, authentication, user-profile

When I turn on my computer, Ubuntu asks for authentication, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Ubuntu asking for authentication]

It asks for a password even when I try to switch Wi-Fi and every time I turn the computer off.

There is only one user on the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have enabled autologin, i.e. you are immediately booting into your desktop without having to provide your user name and password. Normally, your keyring used to store diverse credentials is automatically unlocked when you log in. With autologin, it is not.

If you want to continue autologin, you will need to reduce security more by setting the password of the keyring to blank:

1. Open "Passwords and Keys"
   [image]
2. Right-click the "Login" folder and select "Change password". You will need to give your login password. In the next dialog, do not enter any password, i.e., leave blanc, and hit "Continue".

Alternatively, turn off autologin. Then you will provide a password after the system starts up, and the keyring is then automatically unlocked. This is a much safer approach, which is therefore recommended.

To turn off autologin:

1. Head to "Settings" - "Users" tab
2. Click the <kbd>Unlock</kbd> button: you must provide your password.
3. Turn the checkmark next to "Automatic login"  off.

Comment: +1 for "Alternatively, turn off autologin. Then you will provide a password after the system starts up, and the keyring is then automatically unlocked. This is a much safer approach, which is therefore recommended."

Comment: Any idea why this would happen when autologin is off and the password is set?

Comment: In my case, the problem was that Chrome Remote Desktop screwed with all the settings under the hood and removing it fixed a bunch of issues. Before uninstalling, toggling autologin on/off didn't even work because the "unlock" button for the settings was disabled for me. `sudo apt-get remove chrome-remote-desktop && sudo apt-get autoremove` to fix.

Comment: @Sam your comment should become a answer, that solved the issue for me, I would never realize it was the reason